# How to write code to make the LED’s ﬂash in the following sequence?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

How to write code like this sequence? What is the meaning of 4 decimal?
For this, we had to add a delay in the code

```
led_Pin_1 1 0 0 0 
led_Pin_2 0 1 0 0 
led_Pin_3 0 0 1 0 
led_Pin_4 0 0 0 1
```

my code, It is working. But I need to convert this code to the above sequence?

```
int led_Pin_1 = 11;
int led_Pin_2 = 10;
int led_Pin_3 = 9;
int led_Pin_4 = 8;

void setup() {
  pinMode(led_Pin_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_Pin_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_Pin_3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_Pin_4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_1, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_2, HIGH);
  delay(200);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_3, HIGH);
  delay(200);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_4, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(led_Pin_1, LOW);
  delay(300);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_2, LOW);
  delay(300);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_3, LOW);
  delay(300);
   digitalWrite(led_Pin_4, LOW);
  delay(300);
}
```

If a change like this, what is that meaning

```
LED1 1 0 0 0
LED2 1 1 0 0 
LED3 1 1 1 0
LED4 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: I suggest you stop and read up on `arrays`: how to define them and how to store and retrieve values from them. Also `for loops` and `conditionals`. Good luck.

Comment: I do not understand your questions, nor your two sets of those 4 lines of behavior description. Please elaborate a bit. I can easily see what your code is doing, but that does not fit to any of the two given 4 lines descriptions. And I do not understand what you want instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Array](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/array/).

First, you need to create an array for your LEDs. Then create a function to set the proper value for this array. After that, you can simply assign desired values inside a loop.

A good to use array is that you can change the size easily without modifying all codes.

```
// Number of LEDs
#define ARRAY_SIZE 4

//Pin definitions
#define LED_PIN_1 11
#define LED_PIN_2 10
#define LED_PIN_3 9
#define LED_PIN_4 8

// Array that holds led pin numbers
const int led_pins[ARRAY_SIZE] = {LED_PIN_4, LED_PIN_3, LED_PIN_2, LED_PIN_1};

// a temp array to hold led values
int led_array_value[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};

void display(int *input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        digitalWrite(led_pins[i], input[i]);
    }
}

void setup()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        pinMode(led_pins[i], OUTPUT);
    }
}

void loop()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        // reset all leds to 0
        memset(led_array_value, 0, sizeof(led_array_value));
        // turn on current led
        led_array_value[i] = 1;
        display(led_array_value);
        delay(500);
    }
}
```